# Python KeyError using Random

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program goes to a site, gets the json file and then outputs a random value from a key.

This is how I thought it would work

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request
import json
import random

url = Request("https://splash.wtf/base.json", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

serial = json.loads(data)

def generate():
    return "".join([random.choice(serial['hello']) for x in range(1)])

print(generate())
```

this is the json file

```
{
  "test": {
    "product1": "2",
    "product2": "3"
  }
}
```

Now that raises a KeyError, I saw on stackoverflow that someone said to change my `return`to     `return "".join([random.choice(list(serial.keys())) for x in range(1)])` however that doesn't allow for me to pick from what tree or key I want the value of,. how'd I go about?

Comment: @Sajad it requires a *sequence* to work correctly... although if you have a `dict` whose keys are `range(len(the_dict))` then it'll just happen to work properly

Comment: If i understood you correctly, this would work properly: `"".join(random.choice([d['test'][x] for x in list(d['test'].keys())]))`